# sub align only text underneath one element

Tags: html, css

When I try to create a character `c` as sub-aligned, the followed `bar` text in table row also gets sub-aligned (very unintuitive).

```
<table> 
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>foo<sel style="vertical-align: sub">c</sel></td>
    <td>bar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Can someone point out, what I am doing wrong or how to fix this.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aaL06scu/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```css
td {
  vertical-align:baseline;
}
sel {
  vertical-align:sub;
}
```

```html
<table> 
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>foo<sel>c</sel></td>
    <td>bar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**From the official CSS specification:**

> Lower the baseline of the box to the proper position for subscripts of the parent's box.
>   https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align

**Explanation (Why this happens):**
The `<tbody>` is using `vertical-align:middle;`. These rule verticaly center the whole content of `<tbody>`. The `<td>` element inherit this rule. And you can see the whole content (with subscript) is on the middle. The whole content with subscript is a little bit higher than without the subscript and the middle is not on the middle of the letters, because the subscript extend the height of the whole text. If you want to set the letters to one line you have to `vertical-align` to the baseline. The baseline is the position or line where the letters will be placed. If you do that on all contents of a row the text (not in subscript) should be on one line (see example).

Comment: Thanks. Can you perhaps elaborate a bit, why `vertical-align: inherit` does not work as expected?

Answer (score 3):

Use `<sub>` tag instead

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>foo<sub>c</sub></td>
    <td>bar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Output:**
test foo<sub>c</sub> bar

For more reference on `<sub>` check  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_sub.asp

Comment: In my real code, `sel` has meaning for the content. In contrast, `sub` is a formatting tag, which gives no meaning to the enclosed content.